# PropertyInfo.SetValue of child object?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a method like this:

```
var foo = new Foo();
MapObject(myMap, foo);

private void MapObject(Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> map, object myObject)
{
  foreach(var key in map.Keys)
  {
    int someValue = myDataSet.GetValue(key);

    PropertyInfo pInfo = map[key];
    pInfo.SetValue(myObject, someValue, null);
  }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes, PropertyInfo refers to a property that is in a child class of myObject. For example:

```
class Foo
{
  Bar b { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
  string Test { get; set; }
}
```

When this happens, PropertyInfo.SetValue throws a type exception because it can't set property Test on object Foo. I have no way of knowing which class the current PropertyInfo belongs to (it's part of a strange custom ORM). Is there a way to know which object the PropertyInfo was derived from?

Comment: Are you saying you have a reference for `Bar` but not the `Foo` that it's a property of? If that's the case, there is no way to get `Foo` from `Bar`.

Comment: I rewrote the question to make the problem clearer, hopefully..?

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to set `Bar.Test` to `null`, then you would invoke this:

```
pInfo.SetValue(myObject.Bar, 100, null);
```

This is semantically equivalent to:

```
myObject.Bar.Test = null;
```

Of course, in your example this would throw an exception, since `myObject.Bar` will be `null`.